# I tried a lot to use jinja to make two variables inside of each other but I don't know to do this

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I tried a lot to use more than one variable in the same syntax like this
{{question["answer{{i}}"]}}

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want, it is not clear from what little you have written. Use codeblocks with \`\`\` `code` \`\`\`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `{{}}` inside the curly brackets. I'm entirely sure what you want to achieve with this, but here are a few guesses:

- `{{question[f"answer{i}"]}}`
- `{{question[i]}}`